# Should every code for the Wordpress plgins be included in the functions and hooked with the Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started the Plugin development for the Wordpress, but finding it little difficult to understand. Looks like everything should be hooked with the wordpess to get it run and moreover are there all the global variables that i need to use.

I am making a video plugin and designed some of the forms and display page, but didn't went through the templates, is it compulsory to follow the template structure or we can design our on layout.

I am pretty much confused about all this. Can someone explain a little.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to follow all the templates, you can simply create your own design and if possible allow/tell the users of the plugin how they can modify the look of the plugin.